# How would I know which one to use Gremlin and Tinkerpop

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I would like to implement a graph database in our company and wanted your expert help on this. I have a data model. and want to put it into AWS Neptune, but I don't know if I want Tinkerpop or a property graph. I am a newbie. How do I go about getting this data into neptune? Can someone tell me how to start or basics of getting data loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Apache TinkerPop is a graph computing framework that includes the Gremlin query language. It is designed for use with property graphs.

Amazon Neptune supports Apache TinkerPop/Gremlin. Loading data into Amazon Neptune can be done via the supported query languages or via the Neptune bulk load API.